# C#: Using label I display the current date and time in the form, but I can't add this data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Using a 'label' I can display the date and time on the form, but I can't insert it into SQL Server. I don't know how to call it in the String InsertQuery= ?.

Here is the 'label' code which is displayed in the form:

```
label5.Text = DateTimeOffset.Now.DateTime.ToLongDateString(); // Date 
label10.Text = DateTimeOffset.Now.DateTime.ToLongTimeString(); // Time
```

Here is the 'save' button code which is inside the save.

```
 conn.Close();

 conn.Open();
 String InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Stocks_Item VALUES('" + combo_main_type.Text + "','" + txt_stock_code.Text +"')";

 SqlDataAdapter execute = new SqlDataAdapter(InsertQuery, conn);
 execute.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

 MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

I also created two columns in a SQL Server table `Stocks_Item`:

```
Main_Item_Type | Stock_code| Date | Time
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: If you're in control of the data schema, I'd recommend you combine Date and Time into a single field, and seeing as it it looks you want to set it to the current date/time at the point you insert a record, I'd think it should be called  `Creation_Timestamp` or something similar (or `When_added` if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Don't **concatenate** together your SQL queries! This opens the door to SQL injection attacks.

Use **parametrized queries** instead!

Also: do **not** use names like `Date` or `Time` for your column names - those are **reserved T-SQL keywords** - try to use something **more expressive**, something that belongs to your problem domain - not just these overly generic column names.

Something like this:

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Stocks_Item (StockDate, StockTime) VALUES(@StockDate, @StockTime);";

SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);    

// define and set parameters
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@StockDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@StockTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

conn.Open();
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: i tryed this but over this place it show error  DateTime.Now;

Comment: Failed to cnvert paramete value from a DateTime to a TimeSpan.

Comment: @MohammedAlthaf: updated my response - am I correct to assume the error happened on the **second** parameter -  `@StockTime` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Shows you are working with Web Forms,so alter your query like below and it will work.

```
String InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Stocks_Item VALUES('" + combo_main_type.Text + "','" + txt_stock_code.Text +"','" + label5.Text.ToLongDateString() +"','" + label10.Text.ToLongTimeString() +"')";
```

Comment: You should **not** recommend an approach that is **this vulnerable** to SQL injection attacks! ***ALWAYS*** use parametrized queries instead

Comment: thanks for additional input @marc_s. and i only gave the solution to the problem he questioned.I dint taught him coding standards just used his current structure to resolve his issue :)

Comment: i tryed the above string InsertQuery = ''content " ... now i am getting error saying.. Conversion failed when converting date and/ortime from character String